# assertEq is showing error when written in the test file foundry

Tags: foundry, remix-tests, assert

I am writing the test by following the lesson 7 tutorial and got this error, even I imported Test from forge-std
**Undeclared identifier. Did you mean "assert"?**
this is the actual error

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.18;
import {Test, console} from "forge-std/Test.sol";
import {FundMe} from "../src/FundMe.sol";

contract FundMeTest {
    FundMe fundme;

    function setup() external {
        fundme = new FundMe();
    }

    function checkMminimumDollar() public {
        assertEq(fundme.MINIMUM_USD(), 5e18);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inherit the test.sol in your test contract.

Like this :

```
contract FundMeTest is Test {
    FundMe fundme;

    function setup() external {
        fundme = new FundMe();
    }

    function checkMminimumDollar() public {
        assertEq(fundme.MINIMUM_USD(), 5e18);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks , I got it